# Find largest palindromic substring, algorithm complexity

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, palindrome

You are given a string e.g. `"acdfdcqqc"` and need to create an algorithm to find the largest palindromic substring, in our case `"cdfdc"`. It's easy to devise a O(n^2) algorithm by creating an array of size 2n and each time computing the length of the largest palindrome with that point for center i.e.:

```
a  -  c  -  d  -  f  -  d  -  c  -  q  -  q  -  c
1  0  1  0  1  0  5  0  1  0  1  0  1  4  1  0  1
```

For each of the 2n possible starting points I move in both direction finding the length of the largest palindrome starting at that position. So for each of the 2n operations I do at most O(n) operations, hence the O(n^2) time complexity.

I know it can be done in linear time using a fancier algo: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_palindromic_substring .

But assuming that the string we are handling are extracted from natural English text. If we pick a position at random in an English text, the expected symmetry that we might expect to find is quite low. I would even say that the expected symetry is of less than one character on each side. 
Therefore, is it ok for me to say that my algorithm is doing 2n times expected constant time operations, making the algorithm O(n) on average ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expected running time of an algorithm is the average running time of the algorithm over all possible inputs. (See Chapter 5 of [CLRS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introduction_to_Algorithms).) As the textbook points out, it is not always easy to work this out, and sometimes it is useful to use an alternative: the running-time of the algorithm on a randomly-selected input. But the principle is the same: the notion of "expected running-time" is *probabilistic*, and only applies in aggregate to a large number of applications of the algorithm.

By contrast, the "worst-case running-time" is the worst running time of the algorithm on any input (of each length). That is also not always easy to compute, but it is amenable to least upper-bound computations, which are fine in the case of big-O notation because O(f(n)) only says that f(n) is an upper-bound.

If you apply an algorithm on a restricted set of inputs, you can specify either expected or worst-case running-time over that restricted set; if the inputs are not uniformly distributed over the range of possible inputs, you should take that into account when computed expected running time.

In the case of palindrome length, if the inputs are randomly-selected substrings of English text, the expected length of the largest palindrome will be (slightly) longer than the expected length of the largest palindrome of a text randomly selected from the entire universe of strings whose characters are drawn from the set of lower-case letters and the space character. But for both of these sets of inputs, the expected length of the longest palindrome is O(1).

So it is fine to say that your algorithm is "expected O(n)", although you should also specify the nature of the range of input strings. But if you cannot control the input to the algorithm, the worst-case running time is also relevant, since it is easy to craft a worst-case input for your naïve algorithm, and so a DoS attack on it is clearly feasible.

Answer (score 5):

No.

In algorithm design, to say that an algorithm runs in expected `O(n)` time means that it does so *for every possible input*. That is, the expectation should be on the randomness of the algorithm (internal coin flips), not on the fact that the input is chosen uniformly at random from a restricted set.

However, it doesn't mean that your algorithm is not good. It is OK to use the fact that the input is restricted to English texts, hence possessing certain properties making the algorithm faster than on general inputs. But the terminology you're using (expected `O(n)` time) is reserved for algorithms whose running time is expected to be `O(n)` on every input.

Comment: That's *not* what "expected" time means. You're describing "worst-case" time. Quicksort is expected O(n log n); hash-table lookup is expected O(n); those are both commonly heard. (Worst-case are O(n²) and O(n), respectively. Which is more useful for your use cases?)

Comment: @rici, While Quicksort's worst-case time is O(n²), its expected running time is O(n) *on every input*. Bad inputs are not rare, they don't exist. The algorithm described in the question, on the other hand, assumes that the majority of inputs are "good", and therefore it usually runs in O(n). But not in expectation. Quicksort is fast because of its internal randomness, not because of the distribution of its inputs.

Comment: I was thinking about all those algorithms about planar graph using the Eurler formula (working only for planar graphs) to find the average complexity. They are not handling the most general graph cases. It seems ok to embed some prior knowledge into the computation of the average time complexity, as long as it is clear in the statement that we are concerned only by a subset of the cases. No ?

Comment: Bad inputs for quicksort clearly exist. That's why modern libraries use introsort or similar.

Comment: @user3091275, yes, it's OK to embed prior knowledge into the computation of the running time, but in the case of the current question, contrary to planar graph algorithms, the prior knowledge doesn't apply for every input, but only for the majority of inputs. Hence, the suggested algorithm will fail to have an expected linear running time on certain inputs.

Comment: @rici, you're right about the existence of bad inputs for Quicksort. But the bad inputs do not cause Quicksort to have an expected running time of more than O(n). The analysis of Quicksort's expected running time applies to every input.

Comment: @user3091275: i think the expected palindrome length in a substring of an english text is *longer* than the expected length in random text from the alphabet consisting of 26 letters and a space. But in both cases, the expected length is less than 4.

Comment: @snakile: Expected running time is a probabilistic metric, and cannot be applied to a single input. Please reread CLRS. (Or see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Average-case_complexity))

Comment: @snakile: rereading this thread, i see a point of agreement. You are thinking of quicksort with randomized pivots, which certainly has stochastic running time. But that's not the canonical algorithm; qs is always expected O(n log n) unless you use the end of the partition as pivit and the input is likely to be sorted. (Median of first/mid/last avoids this problem while remaining deterministic.) Stochastic algorithms' running time is certainly probabilistic on a single input, but as CLRS says, qs and other algs have expected behaviour based on the randomness of the input...

Comment: In my first comment, I mentioned hash lookup, but mistyped the expected runtime, which is O(1). But a hash is (usually) completely deterministic.